# Как выделить организацию и вход в здание при загрузке карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На сайте в разделе "Контакты" использую Яндекс.карты JS API. Есть ли способ при загрузке карты выделить конкретную организацию, чтобы отобразилась стрелка с указанием входа в здание? Ниже пример того, что я хочу получить при загрузке карты.

[image: Пример, как должен выглядеть конечный результат:]

Answer (score 0):

В JS API такой возможности нет.